# How t solve "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error" in VS'13

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-5, asp.net-mvc-5

I am running a application in **Visual Studio 2013** and for Entity framework used **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012**. Everything alright from beginning but when I used those command for using **HtmlHelpers** inside my project that time got those error [Error Code  0x80070032 ]:-
[image: Error Code 0x80070032]

My Web Config Code:-

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory,System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="SportsStore.WebUI" />
    <add namespace="SportsStore.WebUI.HtmlHelpers"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
 </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also try this project which is given on Pro MVC 4.0 and solution is :-

Add this line on top of your 'List' View and don't need to any change/add any line in Web-Config file.

```
@using SportsStore.WebUI.HtmlHelpers
```

Hope this works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you are editing the web.config within the Views folder in MVC, not the project root web.config. The web.config in Views folder will have all the necessary sections for Razor etc. and that is the file Razor Configuration would use to resolve namespaces.

If you are making changes to the Views folder web.config, make sure you are not missing the configSections declaration (ex below for MVC4)

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
```

Comment: Now, I don't miss config section...but don't add section group. But after adding your provide lines now I get server error and error indicates the first line of SectionGroup

<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">

Comment: Noticing you are using MVC5 in VS2013. Fastest fix would be "create a new MVC Project type and copy the web.config entries from the Views folder created by the scaffold in VS2013. Otherwise I don't know the public token etc.

Comment: I don't change any default code what VS'13 generate. But for adding 'HtmlHelpers' in the project I just add given 'Web-Config' code what I get from PRO MVC 5.0 Book.

Comment: Odd, try removing your custom namespaces from web.config and add an @using statement to that namespace in the view? That rules out a bad namespace at least

Comment: And I want to make sure, did you add this code to the web.config in the Views folder, or the root of the project (there are 2)?

Comment: If I write @Using in my view then I haven't write those code in 'Web-Config' file. But, at future it hamper on project.
Ab-course I write those code in the root 'Web-Config' file.